# How to prepare SVG code from Inkscape for Angular JS / Angular Material app directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I forked [a CodePen app](https://codepen.io/team/AngularMaterial/pen/mVxgbg) by the Angular Material Team and am trying to replace their user avatar icon with an icon I made in Inkscape.

This is their code, in an app directive template field:

```
<svg class="user-avatar" viewBox="0 0 128 128" height="64" width="64" pointer-events="none" display="block" > <path fill="#FF8A80" d="M0 0h128v128H0z"/> <path fill="#FFE0B2" d="M36.3 94.8c6.4 7.3 16.2 12.1 27.3 12.4 10.7-.3 20.3-4.7 26.7-11.6l.2.1c-17-13.3-12.9-23.4-8.5-28.6 1.3-1.2 2.8-2.5 4.4-3.9l13.1-11c1.5-1.2 2.6-3 2.9-5.1.6-4.4-2.5-8.4-6.9-9.1-1.5-.2-3 0-4.3.6-.3-1.3-.4-2.7-1.6-3.5-1.4-.9-2.8-1.7-4.2-2.5-7.1-3.9-14.9-6.6-23-7.9-5.4-.9-11-1.2-16.1.7-3.3 1.2-6.1 3.2-8.7 5.6-1.3 1.2-2.5 2.4-3.7 3.7l-1.8 1.9c-.3.3-.5.6-.8.8-.1.1-.2 0-.4.2.1.2.1.5.1.6-1-.3-2.1-.4-3.2-.2-4.4.6-7.5 4.7-6.9 9.1.3 2.1 1.3 3.8 2.8 5.1l11 9.3c1.8 1.5 3.3 3.8 4.6 5.7 1.5 2.3 2.8 4.9 3.5 7.6 1.7 6.8-.8 13.4-5.4 18.4-.5.6-1.1 1-1.4 1.7-.2.6-.4 1.3-.6 2-.4 1.5-.5 3.1-.3 4.6.4 3.1 1.8 6.1 4.1 8.2 3.3 3 8 4 12.4 4.5 5.2.6 10.5.7 15.7.2 4.5-.4 9.1-1.2 13-3.4 5.6-3.1 9.6-8.9 10.5-15.2M76.4 46c.9 0 1.6.7 1.6 1.6 0 .9-.7 1.6-1.6 1.6-.9 0-1.6-.7-1.6-1.6-.1-.9.7-1.6 1.6-1.6zm-25.7 0c.9 0 1.6.7 1.6 1.6 0 .9-.7 1.6-1.6 1.6-.9 0-1.6-.7-1.6-1.6-.1-.9.7-1.6 1.6-1.6z"/> <path fill="#E0F7FA" d="M105.3 106.1c-.9-1.3-1.3-1.9-1.3-1.9l-.2-.3c-.6-.9-1.2-1.7-1.9-2.4-3.2-3.5-7.3-5.4-11.4-5.7 0 0 .1 0 .1.1l-.2-.1c-6.4 6.9-16 11.3-26.7 11.6-11.2-.3-21.1-5.1-27.5-12.6-.1.2-.2.4-.2.5-3.1.9-6 2.7-8.4 5.4l-.2.2s-.5.6-1.5 1.7c-.9 1.1-2.2 2.6-3.7 4.5-3.1 3.9-7.2 9.5-11.7 16.6-.9 1.4-1.7 2.8-2.6 4.3h109.6c-3.4-7.1-6.5-12.8-8.9-16.9-1.5-2.2-2.6-3.8-3.3-5z"/> <circle fill="#444" cx="76.3" cy="47.5" r="2"/> <circle fill="#444" cx="50.7" cy="47.6" r="2"/> <path fill="#444" d="M48.1 27.4c4.5 5.9 15.5 12.1 42.4 8.4-2.2-6.9-6.8-12.6-12.6-16.4C95.1 20.9 92 10 92 10c-1.4 5.5-11.1 4.4-11.1 4.4H62.1c-1.7-.1-3.4 0-5.2.3-12.8 1.8-22.6 11.1-25.7 22.9 10.6-1.9 15.3-7.6 16.9-10.2z"/> </svg>
```

The code I see in Inkscape's XML editor or when opening the SVG file with Notepad++ is quite a bit different:

```
<svg
   xmlns:osb="http://www.openswatchbook.org/uri/2009/osb"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="rb icon.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4">
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient4179"
       osb:paint="solid">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop4181" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.6394886"
     inkscape:cx="-607.16873"
     inkscape:cy="903.12934"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     showborder="false"
     showguides="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1536"
     inkscape:window-height="801"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <circle
       style="fill:#009cf0;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1"
       id="path3336"
       cx="-602.85712"
       cy="69.505058"
       r="151.42857" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"
       id="rect4158"
       width="193.80003"
       height="144.85301"
       x="-699.19604"
       y="24.652056" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"
       id="rect4162"
       width="155.71428"
       height="155.71428"
       x="373.2374"
       y="322.82352"
       transform="matrix(-0.70710678,0.70710678,-0.70710678,-0.70710678,0,0)" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"
       id="rect4173"
       width="19.512196"
       height="71.951218"
       x="-682.92682"
       y="-47.637794"
       ry="9.7560978" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;"
       x="-635.36584"
       y="20.654888"
       id="text4195"
       sodipodi:linespacing="127%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan4197"
         x="-635.36584"
         y="20.654888"
         style="line-height:127%;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-variant:normal;font-size:60px;text-anchor:start;text-align:start;writing-mode:lr;fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1">R</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="-597.46344"
       y="54.801228"
       id="text4199"
       sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan4201"
         x="-597.46344"
         y="54.801228"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:60px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1">B</tspan></text>
    <path
       style="fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.67507702;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m -505.412,36.002405 20.333,0 0,38.1298 -20.333,0 z"
       id="rect4207"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.67507702;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m -719.52832,35.102183 20.337,0 0,38.1298 -20.337,0 z"
       id="rect4207-6"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="rect4307"
       width="47.575813"
       height="54.895168"
       x="-626.08392"
       y="115.31452" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

and when I try replacing the default user avatar SVG with mine it breaks the website. The web console says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

Here's the directive with the original SVG:

```
app.directive('userAvatar', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    template: '<svg class="user-avatar" viewBox="0 0 128 128" height="64" width="64" pointer-events="none" display="block" > <path fill="#FF8A80" d="M0 0h128v128H0z"/> <path fill="#FFE0B2" d="M36.3 94.8c6.4 7.3 16.2 12.1 27.3 12.4 10.7-.3 20.3-4.7 26.7-11.6l.2.1c-17-13.3-12.9-23.4-8.5-28.6 1.3-1.2 2.8-2.5 4.4-3.9l13.1-11c1.5-1.2 2.6-3 2.9-5.1.6-4.4-2.5-8.4-6.9-9.1-1.5-.2-3 0-4.3.6-.3-1.3-.4-2.7-1.6-3.5-1.4-.9-2.8-1.7-4.2-2.5-7.1-3.9-14.9-6.6-23-7.9-5.4-.9-11-1.2-16.1.7-3.3 1.2-6.1 3.2-8.7 5.6-1.3 1.2-2.5 2.4-3.7 3.7l-1.8 1.9c-.3.3-.5.6-.8.8-.1.1-.2 0-.4.2.1.2.1.5.1.6-1-.3-2.1-.4-3.2-.2-4.4.6-7.5 4.7-6.9 9.1.3 2.1 1.3 3.8 2.8 5.1l11 9.3c1.8 1.5 3.3 3.8 4.6 5.7 1.5 2.3 2.8 4.9 3.5 7.6 1.7 6.8-.8 13.4-5.4 18.4-.5.6-1.1 1-1.4 1.7-.2.6-.4 1.3-.6 2-.4 1.5-.5 3.1-.3 4.6.4 3.1 1.8 6.1 4.1 8.2 3.3 3 8 4 12.4 4.5 5.2.6 10.5.7 15.7.2 4.5-.4 9.1-1.2 13-3.4 5.6-3.1 9.6-8.9 10.5-15.2M76.4 46c.9 0 1.6.7 1.6 1.6 0 .9-.7 1.6-1.6 1.6-.9 0-1.6-.7-1.6-1.6-.1-.9.7-1.6 1.6-1.6zm-25.7 0c.9 0 1.6.7 1.6 1.6 0 .9-.7 1.6-1.6 1.6-.9 0-1.6-.7-1.6-1.6-.1-.9.7-1.6 1.6-1.6z"/> <path fill="#E0F7FA" d="M105.3 106.1c-.9-1.3-1.3-1.9-1.3-1.9l-.2-.3c-.6-.9-1.2-1.7-1.9-2.4-3.2-3.5-7.3-5.4-11.4-5.7 0 0 .1 0 .1.1l-.2-.1c-6.4 6.9-16 11.3-26.7 11.6-11.2-.3-21.1-5.1-27.5-12.6-.1.2-.2.4-.2.5-3.1.9-6 2.7-8.4 5.4l-.2.2s-.5.6-1.5 1.7c-.9 1.1-2.2 2.6-3.7 4.5-3.1 3.9-7.2 9.5-11.7 16.6-.9 1.4-1.7 2.8-2.6 4.3h109.6c-3.4-7.1-6.5-12.8-8.9-16.9-1.5-2.2-2.6-3.8-3.3-5z"/> <circle fill="#444" cx="76.3" cy="47.5" r="2"/> <circle fill="#444" cx="50.7" cy="47.6" r="2"/> <path fill="#444" d="M48.1 27.4c4.5 5.9 15.5 12.1 42.4 8.4-2.2-6.9-6.8-12.6-12.6-16.4C95.1 20.9 92 10 92 10c-1.4 5.5-11.1 4.4-11.1 4.4H62.1c-1.7-.1-3.4 0-5.2.3-12.8 1.8-22.6 11.1-25.7 22.9 10.6-1.9 15.3-7.6 16.9-10.2z"/> </svg>'
  };
});
```

I've tried a dozen variations on this, but using a 1-line style where I insert only `class="user-avatar"` into the new XML here is what the updated directive looks like:

```
app.directive('userAvatar', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    //template: '<svg class="user-avatar" viewBox="0 0 128 128" height="64" width="64" pointer-events="none" display="block" > <path fill="#FF8A80" d="M0 0h128v128H0z"/> <path fill="#FFE0B2" d="M36.3 94.8c6.4 7.3 16.2 12.1 27.3 12.4 10.7-.3 20.3-4.7 26.7-11.6l.2.1c-17-13.3-12.9-23.4-8.5-28.6 1.3-1.2 2.8-2.5 4.4-3.9l13.1-11c1.5-1.2 2.6-3 2.9-5.1.6-4.4-2.5-8.4-6.9-9.1-1.5-.2-3 0-4.3.6-.3-1.3-.4-2.7-1.6-3.5-1.4-.9-2.8-1.7-4.2-2.5-7.1-3.9-14.9-6.6-23-7.9-5.4-.9-11-1.2-16.1.7-3.3 1.2-6.1 3.2-8.7 5.6-1.3 1.2-2.5 2.4-3.7 3.7l-1.8 1.9c-.3.3-.5.6-.8.8-.1.1-.2 0-.4.2.1.2.1.5.1.6-1-.3-2.1-.4-3.2-.2-4.4.6-7.5 4.7-6.9 9.1.3 2.1 1.3 3.8 2.8 5.1l11 9.3c1.8 1.5 3.3 3.8 4.6 5.7 1.5 2.3 2.8 4.9 3.5 7.6 1.7 6.8-.8 13.4-5.4 18.4-.5.6-1.1 1-1.4 1.7-.2.6-.4 1.3-.6 2-.4 1.5-.5 3.1-.3 4.6.4 3.1 1.8 6.1 4.1 8.2 3.3 3 8 4 12.4 4.5 5.2.6 10.5.7 15.7.2 4.5-.4 9.1-1.2 13-3.4 5.6-3.1 9.6-8.9 10.5-15.2M76.4 46c.9 0 1.6.7 1.6 1.6 0 .9-.7 1.6-1.6 1.6-.9 0-1.6-.7-1.6-1.6-.1-.9.7-1.6 1.6-1.6zm-25.7 0c.9 0 1.6.7 1.6 1.6 0 .9-.7 1.6-1.6 1.6-.9 0-1.6-.7-1.6-1.6-.1-.9.7-1.6 1.6-1.6z"/> <path fill="#E0F7FA" d="M105.3 106.1c-.9-1.3-1.3-1.9-1.3-1.9l-.2-.3c-.6-.9-1.2-1.7-1.9-2.4-3.2-3.5-7.3-5.4-11.4-5.7 0 0 .1 0 .1.1l-.2-.1c-6.4 6.9-16 11.3-26.7 11.6-11.2-.3-21.1-5.1-27.5-12.6-.1.2-.2.4-.2.5-3.1.9-6 2.7-8.4 5.4l-.2.2s-.5.6-1.5 1.7c-.9 1.1-2.2 2.6-3.7 4.5-3.1 3.9-7.2 9.5-11.7 16.6-.9 1.4-1.7 2.8-2.6 4.3h109.6c-3.4-7.1-6.5-12.8-8.9-16.9-1.5-2.2-2.6-3.8-3.3-5z"/> <circle fill="#444" cx="76.3" cy="47.5" r="2"/> <circle fill="#444" cx="50.7" cy="47.6" r="2"/> <path fill="#444" d="M48.1 27.4c4.5 5.9 15.5 12.1 42.4 8.4-2.2-6.9-6.8-12.6-12.6-16.4C95.1 20.9 92 10 92 10c-1.4 5.5-11.1 4.4-11.1 4.4H62.1c-1.7-.1-3.4 0-5.2.3-12.8 1.8-22.6 11.1-25.7 22.9 10.6-1.9 15.3-7.6 16.9-10.2z"/> </svg>'
    template: '<svg   class="user-avatar"  xmlns:osb="http://www.openswatchbook.org/uri/2009/osb"    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"    xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"    width="210mm"    height="297mm"    viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"    id="svg2"    version="1.1"    inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"    sodipodi:docname="rb icon.svg">   <defs      id="defs4">     <linearGradient        id="linearGradient4179"        osb:paint="solid">       <stop          style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;"          offset="0"          id="stop4181" />     </linearGradient>   </defs>   <sodipodi:namedview      id="base"      pagecolor="#ffffff"      bordercolor="#666666"      borderopacity="1.0"      inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"      inkscape:pageshadow="2"      inkscape:zoom="1.6394886"      inkscape:cx="-607.16873"      inkscape:cy="903.12934"      inkscape:document-units="px"      inkscape:current-layer="layer1"      showgrid="false"      showborder="false"      showguides="false"      inkscape:window-width="1536"      inkscape:window-height="801"      inkscape:window-x="-8"      inkscape:window-y="-8"      inkscape:window-maximized="1" />   <metadata      id="metadata7">     <rdf:RDF>       <cc:Work          rdf:about="">         <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>         <dc:type            rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />         <dc:title></dc:title>       </cc:Work>     </rdf:RDF>   </metadata>   <g      inkscape:label="Layer 1"      inkscape:groupmode="layer"      id="layer1">     <circle        style="fill:#009cf0;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1"        id="path3336"        cx="-602.85712"        cy="69.505058"        r="151.42857" />     <rect        style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"        id="rect4158"        width="193.80003"        height="144.85301"        x="-699.19604"        y="24.652056" />     <rect        style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"        id="rect4162"        width="155.71428"        height="155.71428"        x="373.2374"        y="322.82352"        transform="matrix(-0.70710678,0.70710678,-0.70710678,-0.70710678,0,0)" />     <rect        style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"        id="rect4173"        width="19.512196"        height="71.951218"        x="-682.92682"        y="-47.637794"        ry="9.7560978" />     <text        xml:space="preserve"        style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;"        x="-635.36584"        y="20.654888"        id="text4195"        sodipodi:linespacing="127%"><tspan          sodipodi:role="line"          id="tspan4197"          x="-635.36584"          y="20.654888"          style="line-height:127%;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-variant:normal;font-size:60px;text-anchor:start;text-align:start;writing-mode:lr;fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1">R</tspan></text>     <text        xml:space="preserve"        style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"        x="-597.46344"        y="54.801228"        id="text4199"        sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan          sodipodi:role="line"          id="tspan4201"          x="-597.46344"          y="54.801228"          style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:60px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1">B</tspan></text>     <path        style="fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.67507702;stroke-opacity:1"        d="m -505.412,36.002405 20.333,0 0,38.1298 -20.333,0 z"        id="rect4207"        inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />     <path        style="fill:#009cf0;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.67507702;stroke-opacity:1"        d="m -719.52832,35.102183 20.337,0 0,38.1298 -20.337,0 z"        id="rect4207-6"        inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />     <rect        style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"        id="rect4307"        width="47.575813"        height="54.895168"        x="-626.08392"        y="115.31452" />   </g> </svg>'
  };
});
```

[image]

You can reproduce the error by replacing the original directive with the one above in the CodePen app.

Original: https://codepen.io/team/AngularMaterial/pen/mVxgbg

Broken:   https://codepen.io/hack-r/pen/LRdVPN

Comment: what exactly does "breaks the website" mean?

Comment: @RobertLongson  I use npm's browser-sync tool to watch changes and the Angular module chokes on the code and can't display anything when you add this. Even in Atom (the Github text editor) almost all of this XML shows up in red shading, indicating it can't be interpreted when it's inside a directive. The web console says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

Comment: Stupid question, but to update that original directive, you will need to concatenate all the new SVG's lines into a single line. Are you doing that?  Otherwise you show us a snippet, fiddle, or updated codepen so we can see exactly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Sure, I will add a snippet. *Update: added it.* I thought the answer was going to be that I need to strip out some of the XML fields in the Inkscape code, but I haven't been successful trying that yet. Note that in the snippet I added it's the 1-line version with `class="user-avatar"` but I tried it multiline, with a new class name, with no class name, etc, etc and nothing changed.

Comment: I also tried it with different sizes of the image, with and without compression.

Comment: By snippet, I meant a working example ([MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Something we can see running.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Sorry, I thought that was sufficient to reproduce. Here's the CodePen app though. You can just paste to here and watch it break. https://codepen.io/team/AngularMaterial/pen/mVxgbg  ... and I think this is where I did just that, but I've never used CodePen like this before so I'm scared to share this link.... https://codepen.io/hack-r/pen/LRdVPN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is tipical `"` ,`'` problem You have `'` inside Your string representing svg, change all `'` to `"` and it will work. First of them in svg is `'sans-serif, Normal'`.

Your code breaks because string starts on `'` and ends on first `'` which is inside svg string so next part of code has error syntax.